# where is mac_policy.h to implement mandatory access control kernel extension?

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina, kernel-extension

I'm trying to make a sample kernel extension like from [here](https://www.synack.com/blog/monitoring-process-creation-via-the-kernel-part-i/)
but, I can't find where the `mac_policy.h` is with next command

> sudo find / -iname 'mac_policy.h'

where is it?
should I download something?

my environment is like below.

- macOS Catalina 10.15.1

```
$ uname -rsv  
Darwin 19.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64
```

- Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAC Framework has officially never been supported by Apple for 3rd party kexts, and they don't guarantee ABI compatibility across versions. (The callbacks can have different function signatures in different macOS versions, which makes kernel panics likely.) Its headers were removed from the Kernel.framework around the macOS 10.13 SDK to reflect this lack of support

From macOS 10.15 onwards, you are supposed to use EndpointSecurity instead.